# Drag and Drop Pdf file, Word file, Excel file in Winform C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Drag and Drop Pdf, Ms-word, Excel file in C# windows Applications

Comment: OK... and do you have some kind of question? At the moment it just seems to be a collection of keywords.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with programming?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good place to start first :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-performing-a-drag-and-drop-operation-in-windows-forms